# Low events and low search - selecting year

Tags: low-search, low-events

What is the correct syntax for setting the selected year drop down upon a search?

```
{exp:low_events:archive 
                events_field="events_date_time" 
                show_passed="no" 
                show_future_entries="yes"
                unit='year'
            }
<option {if low_search_low_events:date == date_url} selected="selected"{/if} value="{year}">{year}</option>
{/exp:low_events:archive}
```

This works when unit is set to month, but not year.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the option is the `{year}` val, so use `year` instead of `date_url` in your conditional.

Comment: low_search_low_events:date is outputting dates in the format yyyy-mm so how does yyyy-mm == yyyy ?

Comment: Then add more info to your original question. What's the `name` of the select element that is part of the `option`s you're generating? Better still, what does the full Form tag look like?